# How to resolve favicon.ico not found error on apache

Tags: php, apache

I am getting following error while running index.php file on apache

```
File does not exist: /home/../../../../favicon.ico
```

What does this mean? What should I change to resolve it?

Comment: Where are you seeing that error and from whom? Apache, the PHP script...? What other information is there?

Comment: create favicon.ico and place on root.

Comment: I am not sure if it shows up in your webpage. It shouldn't. If the error shows up in your logs you can safely ignore it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Favicon.ico is an icon file that is displayed next to the URL in the browser bar. (See the StackExchange icon next to the URL).

There is no way to stop browsers requesting it. You can either create a favicon, or create a zero byte file called favicon.ico and place in the web root.

Comment: Or create a 404 response in `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this helps if you are not working from the root directory. 
This eliminated the error for me. It is placed in the head.

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
```