# Codeigniter 404 error logs

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging

Below is my Codeigniter logs. I would really like to clean these up but I cannot find these files/folders errors anywhere can any codeigniter pros suggest a fix.

```
ERROR - 2017-02-24 19:28:48 --> 404 Page Not Found: Faviconico/index
ERROR - 2017-02-24 19:28:48 --> 404 Page Not Found: Faviconico/index
ERROR - 2017-02-24 19:30:48 --> 404 Page Not Found: Faviconico/index
ERROR - 2017-02-24 19:31:28 --> 404 Page Not Found: Well-known/dnt-policy.txt
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: I think the [Faviconico is this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13154783/3585500) and [the fix might be this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33817658/3585500).

Comment: @ourmandave perfect cheers if you put it as an answer ill accept it

Comment: [Here's an answer for the well-known directory 404](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/96427/what-is-the-well-known-directory-and-how-should-i-set-it-up) (which was news to me).